# Error en Calculadora HTML5: TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Creo que el problema esta en la declaración de variables el código aun no esta completo ya que falta funciones por asignar pero las funciones básicas no me están funcionando ej: suma, resta, multiplicación y divicion. con ellos los números.
PD: tambien puede ser problema con el codigo de la pantalla pero no logro ver el problema, el inspector de chrome me dio este error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null
>
> ```
> at init (Calculadora.js:52)
>
> at onload (N_cal.html?display=8%2B10:8)</B>
> ```

```js
var primern;
var segundon;
var resultado2;
function init(){
 //tuve que cambiar la forma de declarar las variables porque buscando lei que
 //el getElementsClassName es para grupo de vaiables y yo solo tenia una y lo cambie por Id
 var pantalla = document.getElementById('pantalla');
 var reset = document.getElementById('reset');
 var backspace = document.getElementById('backspace');
 var porcentaje = document.getElementById('porcentaje');
 var divicion = document.getElementById('divicion');
 var multiplicacion = document.getElementById('multiplicacion');
 var resta = document.getElementById('resta');
 var suma = document.getElementById('suma');
 var igual = document.getElementById('igual');
 var numero1 = document.getElementById('numero1');
 var numero2 = document.getElementById('numero2');
 var numero3 = document.getElementById('numero3');
 var numero4 = document.getElementById('numero4');
 var numero5 = document.getElementById('numero5');
 var numero6 = document.getElementById('numero6');
    var numero7 = document.getElementById('numero7');
 var numero8 = document.getElementById('numero8');
 var numero9 = document.getElementById('numero9');
 var cero = document.getElementById('cero');
 var decimal = document.getElementById('decimal');

numero1.onclick = function(e){
  pantalla.textContent = pantalla.textContent + "1";
 }
numero2.onclick = function(e){
  pantalla.textContent = pantalla.textContent + "2";
 }
numero3.onclick = function(e){
  pantalla.textContent = pantalla.textContent + "3";
 }
numero4.onclick = function(e){
  pantalla.textContent = pantalla.textContent + "4";
 }
numero5.onclick = function(e){
  pantalla.textContent = pantalla.textContent + "5";
 }
numero6.onclick = function(e){
  pantalla.textContent = pantalla.textContent + "6";
 }
numero7.onclick = function(e){
  pantalla.textContent = pantalla.textContent + "7";
 }
numero8.onclick = function(e){
  pantalla.textContent = pantalla.textContent + "8";
 }
numero9.onclick = function(e){
  pantalla.textContent = pantalla.textContent + "9";
 }
cero.onclick = function(e){
  pantalla.textContent = pantalla.textContent + "0";
 }
reset.onclick = function(e){
 recetear();
    }
suma.onclick = function(e){
 primern = pantalla.textContent;
 resultado2 = "+";
 limpiar();
    }
    resta.onclick = function(e){
     primern = pantalla.textContent;
     resultado2 = "-";
     limpiar();
    }
multiplicacion.onclick = function(e){
 primern = pantalla.textContent;
 resultado2 = "*";
 limpiar();
    }
divicion.onclick = function(e){
 primern = pantalla.textContent;
 resultado2 = "/";
 limpiar();
   }
igual.onclick = function(e){
    segundon = pantalla.textContent;
    resolver();
}
}

function limpiar (){
 pantalla.textContent = "";
}
function recetear(){
 pantalla.textContent = "";
 primern = 0;
 segundon = 0;
 resultado2 = "";
}
//esto lo vi en java tube que buscar en mi ordenador donde tenia un ejercicio parecido que tenia.
function resolver(){
 var res = 0;
 switch(resultado2){
  case "+":
  res = parseFloat(primern) + parseFloat(segundon);
  break;
  case "+":
  res = parseFloat(primern) - parseFloat(segundon);
  break
  case "*":
  res = parseFloat(primern) * parseFloat(segundon);
  break
  case "/":
  res = parseFloat(primern) / parseFloat(segundon);
  break
 }
recetear();
pantalla.textContent = res; 
}
```

```css
*{
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
}
.contenedor{
 position:relative;
 top:125px;
 background:black;
}
.resultado{
 font-size:30px;
 font-family: Arial,Helvetica;
 color:white;
 border:0px;
 background:black;
 width:325.8px;
 height:80px;
 text-align:right;
}
.columna1{
 font-size:30px;
 font-family: Arial,Helvetica;
 color:black;
 border:0px;
 background:#D6CFC9;
 width:80px;
 height:80px;
}
.columna2{
 font-size:30px;
 font-family: Arial,Helvetica;
 color:white;
 border:0px;
 background:#FF821C;
 width:80px;
 height:80px;
}
#cero{
 width:162px;
}
.fila{
 font-size:30px;
 font-family: Arial,Helvetica;
 color:black;
 border:0px;
 background:#C9BDB3;
 width:80px;
 height:80px;
}
table{
 background:#7E7E7D;
}
td input:active{
 background:#fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Calculadora</title>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilos.css">

<body onload="init();">
 <div>
  <form>
   <table>
    <tr>
     <td colspan="4"><input class="resultado" id="pantalla" type="text" value=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td><input class="fila" id="reset" type="button" value="AC"></td>
     <td><input class="fila" id="backspace" type="button" value="←"></td>
     <td><input class="fila" id="porcentaje" type="button" value="%"></td>
     <td><input class="columna2" id="divicion" type="button" value="÷"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td><input class="columna1" id="numero7" type="button" value="7"></td>
     <td><input class="columna1" id="numero8" type="button" value="8"></td>
     <td><input class="columna1" id="numero9" type="button" value="9"></td>
     <td><input class="columna2" id="multiplicacion" type="button" value="x"></td>
     
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td><input class="columna1" id="numero4" type="button" value="4"></td>
     <td><input class="columna1" id="numero5" type="button" value="5"></td>
     <td><input class="columna1" id="numero6" type="button" value="6"></td>
     <td><input class="columna2" id="resta" type="button" value="-"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td><input class="columna1" id="numero1" type="button" value="1"></td>
     <td><input class="columna1" id="numero2" type="button" value="2"></td>
     <td><input class="columna1" id="numero3" type="button" value="3"></td>
     <td><input class="columna2" id="suma" type="button" value="+"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td colspan="2"><input class="columna1" id="cero" type="button" value="0"></td>
     <td><input class="columna1" id="decimal" type="button" value="."></td>
     <td><input class="columna2" id="igual" type="button" value="="></td>
     
    </tr>
   </table>
  </form>
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/Calculadora.js"></script> 
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No se ve el error que comentas.

Comment: El error lo muestra google chrome cuando le doy a inspeccionar elemento, pero fuera de eso ¿por que no funciona?

Comment: Deberian de aparecer los numeros que escribes en "la pantalla" o solo debe de aparecer el resultado?

Comment: Tanto números como resultados principales.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El problema es que pantalla es un `input` y entonces no tiene `textContent`, lo que tiene es `value`. Si cambias `pantalla.textContent` por `pantalla.value` la calculadora ya funciona.

Además, como bien indica Marcos en los comentarios, hay un error para la operación del `-`:

```js
var primern;
var segundon;
var resultado2;

function init() {
  //tuve que cambiar la forma de declarar las variables porque buscando lei que
  //el getElementsClassName es para grupo de vaiables y yo solo tenia una y lo cambie por Id
  var pantalla = document.getElementById('pantalla');
  var reset = document.getElementById('reset');
  var backspace = document.getElementById('backspace');
  var porcentaje = document.getElementById('porcentaje');
  var divicion = document.getElementById('divicion');
  var multiplicacion = document.getElementById('multiplicacion');
  var resta = document.getElementById('resta');
  var suma = document.getElementById('suma');
  var igual = document.getElementById('igual');
  var numero1 = document.getElementById('numero1');
  var numero2 = document.getElementById('numero2');
  var numero3 = document.getElementById('numero3');
  var numero4 = document.getElementById('numero4');
  var numero5 = document.getElementById('numero5');
  var numero6 = document.getElementById('numero6');
  var numero7 = document.getElementById('numero7');
  var numero8 = document.getElementById('numero8');
  var numero9 = document.getElementById('numero9');
  var cero = document.getElementById('cero');
  var decimal = document.getElementById('decimal');

  numero1.onclick = function(e) {
    pantalla.value = pantalla.value + "1";
  }
  numero2.onclick = function(e) {
    pantalla.value = pantalla.value + "2";
  }
  numero3.onclick = function(e) {
    pantalla.value = pantalla.value + "3";
  }
  numero4.onclick = function(e) {
    pantalla.value = pantalla.value + "4";
  }
  numero5.onclick = function(e) {
    pantalla.value = pantalla.value + "5";
  }
  numero6.onclick = function(e) {
    pantalla.value = pantalla.value + "6";
  }
  numero7.onclick = function(e) {
    pantalla.value = pantalla.value + "7";
  }
  numero8.onclick = function(e) {
    pantalla.value = pantalla.value + "8";
  }
  numero9.onclick = function(e) {
    pantalla.value = pantalla.value + "9";
  }
  cero.onclick = function(e) {
    pantalla.value = pantalla.value + "0";
  }
  reset.onclick = function(e) {
    recetear();
  }
  suma.onclick = function(e) {
    primern = pantalla.value;
    resultado2 = "+";
    limpiar();
  }
  resta.onclick = function(e) {
    primern = pantalla.value;
    resultado2 = "-";
    limpiar();
  }
  multiplicacion.onclick = function(e) {
    primern = pantalla.value;
    resultado2 = "*";
    limpiar();
  }
  divicion.onclick = function(e) {
    primern = pantalla.value;
    resultado2 = "/";
    limpiar();
  }
  igual.onclick = function(e) {
    segundon = pantalla.value;
    resolver();
  }
}

function limpiar() {
  pantalla.value = "";
}

function recetear() {
  pantalla.value = "";
  primern = 0;
  segundon = 0;
  resultado2 = "";
}
//esto lo vi en java tube que buscar en mi ordenador donde tenia un ejercicio parecido que tenia.
function resolver() {
  var res = 0;
  switch (resultado2) {
    case "+":
      res = parseFloat(primern) + parseFloat(segundon);
      break;
    case "-":
      res = parseFloat(primern) - parseFloat(segundon);
      break
    case "*":
      res = parseFloat(primern) * parseFloat(segundon);
      break
    case "/":
      res = parseFloat(primern) / parseFloat(segundon);
      break
  }
  recetear();
  pantalla.value = res;
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.contenedor {
  position: relative;
  top: 125px;
  background: black;
}

.resultado {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica;
  color: white;
  border: 0px;
  background: black;
  width: 325.8px;
  height: 80px;
  text-align: right;
}

.columna1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica;
  color: black;
  border: 0px;
  background: #D6CFC9;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}

.columna2 {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica;
  color: white;
  border: 0px;
  background: #FF821C;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}

#cero {
  width: 162px;
}

.fila {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica;
  color: black;
  border: 0px;
  background: #C9BDB3;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}

table {
  background: #7E7E7D;
}

td input:active {
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Calculadora</title>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilos.css">

<body onload="init();">
  <div>
    <form>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="4"><input class="resultado" id="pantalla" type="text" value=""></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input class="fila" id="reset" type="button" value="AC"></td>
          <td><input class="fila" id="backspace" type="button" value="←"></td>
          <td><input class="fila" id="porcentaje" type="button" value="%"></td>
          <td><input class="columna2" id="divicion" type="button" value="÷"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input class="columna1" id="numero7" type="button" value="7"></td>
          <td><input class="columna1" id="numero8" type="button" value="8"></td>
          <td><input class="columna1" id="numero9" type="button" value="9"></td>
          <td><input class="columna2" id="multiplicacion" type="button" value="x"></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input class="columna1" id="numero4" type="button" value="4"></td>
          <td><input class="columna1" id="numero5" type="button" value="5"></td>
          <td><input class="columna1" id="numero6" type="button" value="6"></td>
          <td><input class="columna2" id="resta" type="button" value="-"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input class="columna1" id="numero1" type="button" value="1"></td>
          <td><input class="columna1" id="numero2" type="button" value="2"></td>
          <td><input class="columna1" id="numero3" type="button" value="3"></td>
          <td><input class="columna2" id="suma" type="button" value="+"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2"><input class="columna1" id="cero" type="button" value="0"></td>
          <td><input class="columna1" id="decimal" type="button" value="."></td>
          <td><input class="columna2" id="igual" type="button" value="="></td>

        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/Calculadora.js"></script>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias la verdad es que soy nuevo ahora tendre que estudiar este error muchas gracias hermano eres un crack.